# Disable PageSpeed on htm/html files

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-pagespeed

I'm experiencing the issue described [here](https://github.com/pagespeed/mod_pagespeed/issues/633).

Some .htm/.html files show up as blank when pagespeed is enabled.

Seems to be no solution right now other than disabling Pagespeed processing .htm/.html files which I'm fine with as a workaround as I only have a few of them to worry about.

However, in my pagespeed.conf (/etc/httpd/conf.d/pagespeed.conf) when I try to disallow this it has no effect:

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
    # Turn on mod_pagespeed. To completely disable mod_pagespeed, you
    # can set this to "off".
    # ModPagespeed off

    ModPagespeedDisallow "*.htm"
    ModPagespeedDisallow "*.html"

    # ...
</IfModule>
```

Am I putting the ModPagespeedDisallow directives in the right place?

Comment: Could you add the URIs?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/pagespeed/mod_pagespeed/issues/271) one could use:

```
ModPagespeedDisallow *.html*
```

**Context**

> Oops, it appears that \? is not accepted.
>
> Instead you could use:
>
> ```
> ModPagespeedDisallow *
> ModPagespeedAllow *.html*
> ModPagespeedAllow *.jsp*
> ```
>
> Hope this helps.
>
> After chatting with the team we decided this is a documentation issue,
>   that we  just need to be clear that this matches the complete URL
>   including query params.

Comment: Thanks for this - it's not 100% the fix but it has helped.